# Is it acceptable to use a wrapper class to hide errors?

Tags: php, oop, wrapper, helper

Is it okay to wrap a global array in a class to hide the `undefined` errors (and returning false) with OOP? If not, why?

I'm using the following `Input` wrapper class. Mainly using it together with my `FormValidator` class so that I don't have to write `isset()` for N amount of inputs I want to use / check.

```
class Input {
    private $_source;

    public function __construct(Array $source){
        $this->_source = $source;
    }

    public function exists() {
        return !empty($this->_source);
    }

    public function get($input) {
        return (isset($this->_source[$input])) ? $this->_source[$input] : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It can be OK, or it can be overkill. No way to answer objectively. But if you are going to use this class strictly to wrap arrays, it might be a good idea to implement [`ArrayAccess`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) so that you can wrap transparently.

Comment: You shouldn't get *undefined* notices with `isset()`. If you get them, it's probably due to a typo or error in some other part of your code and you definitively want to be aware of that before you release your code.

Comment: But if I don't use a wrapper class like this and have a lot of input I need to check, I would have to write `isset()` every time to make sure it's defined before interacting with it.

Comment: Hmmm.... I suspect I misread the question. You don't mean "I have a class, should I hide the errors it generates?" but "should I write a class to simplify reading of potentially missing variables?". That's what builtin filter functions basically do (except that in procedural style) so I guess the general approach is just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As good comments on your question points out, there is different ways and maybe better built-in concept you could use to solve the problem you pose.

But to answer your question regarding OOP practices in PHP, I would definitively argue that hiding errors in your wrapper class is legal.

I would regard it as a blackbox and the concept of that error might not be known outside since your interface does not document it.

An error handling could be implemented inside your wrapper to later handle those errors in a way that does not need to be known on the outside.

It ok, but all errors should be handled in general and hiding them or swallowing them could give strange behavior.